# How long is the life of rust monsters?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

How long is the life of rust monsters?

How long will a rust monster grow up from a child in the barrel?

Comment: RE: "How long will a rust monster grow up from a child in the barrel?" I don't know what this means. Could the question clarify? It sounds like *either* something's been lost in translation *or* autocorrect changed the intent.

Comment: You didn't play in barrels when you were a kid? I guess it's all Minecraft and Fortnite now.

Comment: I got my first computer at age 22 and I have no idea what the barrel line means in this context.

Comment: I suspect it's a regional thing. I'm coming up on 50 faster than I'd like, and this is the first time I've ever heard of a game called "in barrels" or the phrase "child in the barrel".

Answer (score 8):

According to the *Ecology of the Rust Monster* feature from Dragon Magazine #346, it takes about two years for a newly hatched rust monster to grow to its adult size:

> After approximately a month the eggs hatch, each spilling out a tiny larval rust monster about the length of a man's forearm.  These young have no appendages and look like nothing more than bloated, brownish maggots with moist antennae approximately a foot long.  These antennae possess the same corrosive effects as an adult rust monster's, and **over the next two years grow in size, along with legs, a bony tail, and a hardened carapace**.

The article doesn't specify exactly how long a rust monster can live after reaching adulthood, but it's at least "decades."  The feature details a particularly old, large, and powerful rust monster called o-Akasabi-sama, whose description includes the following:

> Over the decades this monstrosity has destroyed the weapons and holy katanas of numerous master swordsmen...

Comment: That last bit sounds like an in-joke, possibly from an anime or manga.